# Show that a function is continuous on a normed space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, normed-spaces

So I have learned topology and we haven't touched normed space there. However, from my linear algebra class I know that every normed space can naturally induce a metric, so I wonder that, to show $f:X\rightarrow X$ is continuous on the normed space $X$, can we treat $X$ as a metric space and show continuity using $\epsilon$-balls argument (because that's what I'm currently comfortable with).

Anyway, what do we actually mean that a function is continuous when its domain and codomain are some normed space. I'm not very sure about this. Could anyone present a definition and reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you can do that, knowing that the distance is defined by $d(x, y) = \Vert x - y \Vert$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

However, $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs are a bit cumbersome. It's almost always easier to use the topological definition when you can.

Comment: Thank you. Well, but when I think of $\epsilon$-balls, I think them as basis elements of the metric topology, so I wonder if there's a more "topological" argument that you are hinting at?

Comment: A function $f:X \to Y$ of topological spaces is continuous if for every open set $U \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open. It's fairly straightforward to show that those two definitions are equivalent for metric spaces, but this definition has two advantages: 1. it is far more general and 2. it doesn't need to deal with the nitty-gritty $\epsilon$-$\delta$ stuff. ("should I have started with $\epsilon^2/4$?"). It's not as though this approach is completely without sweat, but it's usually much cleaner. Re-reading your comment, you probably already knew all of that, but I'll leave it up.